# Asynchronous implementation JoinAwait in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-entities

I use `System.Linq.Async`, i try to do so but i get error.

```
await _dbContext.Application
    .AsAsyncEnumerable()
    .Join(_dbContext.Users, 
        o => o.IdUser, 
        i => i.Id, 
        (o, i) => new { Id = o.Id })
    .ToListAsync();
```

How I can create query with `JoinAwait` correct ?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Guru Stron, error - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Comment: You can't run multiple queries in parallel on the same context. Remove `AsAsyncEnumerable` and just run simple query. Also why do you want to load full `Application` and `User` tables into memory and then join them there rather than allowing db engine to do what it was designed for?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Guru Stron, I use ms sql. What do you mean “ allowing db engine to do what it was designed for” ?

Comment: I mean that databases such as SQL Server are designed and optimized to perform joins, queries and so on.

Comment: @Guru Stron thanks for help, but i can't understand. have you ever worked with System.Linq.Async?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run multiple queries in parallel on the same context.

Usually there is no reason to load full `Application` and `User` tables into memory from relational database and then join them there rather than allowing db engine to do what it was designed for.  Remove `AsAsyncEnumerable` and just run simple query against your database:

```cs
await _dbContext.Application
    .Join(_dbContext.Users, 
        o => o.IdUser, 
        i => i.Id, 
        (o, i) => new { Id = o.Id })
    .ToListAsync();
```

Or better, if relation between `Application` and `User` exists and it is possible to set up it - add corresponding [navigation properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#definition-of-terms) to your entites and use those to perform joins.

Comment: it's not working, joinawait arror -  'AsyncEnumerable.JoinAwait<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(IAsyncEnumerable<TOuter>, IAsyncEnumerable<TInner>, Func<TOuter, ValueTask<TKey>>, Func<TInner, ValueTask<TKey>>, Func<TOuter, TInner, ValueTask<TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: @ukrainianDev can you please show your code?